# git tries to stat //HEAD when searching for a repo, leading to huge delays on Cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin

I have a fancy shell prompt that executes `git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree` to determine whether we're currently inside a working directory. This causes git to walk up the directory hierarchy looking for a containing git repo. For example, when invoked from my home directory, it stats the following paths, in order:

```
/home/me/.git
/home/me/.git/HEAD
/home/me/HEAD
/home
/home/.git
/home/.git/HEAD
/home/HEAD
/
/.git
/.git/HEAD
//HEAD
```

The last name (`//HEAD`) interacts badly with Cygwin, which interprets it as a UNC file share, and so demand-loads a bunch of extra DLLs and attempts to resolve/contact the server named `HEAD`. This obviously doesn't work too well, especially over a slow network link.

This smells like a bug in git, albeit one that's probably harmless on platforms without the strange interpretation of //, so I'm looking for a workaround.

I've tested with the latest Cygwin git (2.15.0); this was also present in a prior version.

Comment: You may want to bring this up on the git mailing list git@vger.kernel.org . (I think the cygwin mailing list will just be very specifically for the cygwin core, and any packages should be discussed with the package owners.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> git tries to stat `//HEAD`

It has indeed been fixed in upstream, for Git 2.15.x/2.16 (Q1 2018), and it corrects the start-up sequence so that a repository could be placed immediately under the root directory again (which was broken at around Git 2.13).

See [commit fa4d8c7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa4d8c783d780191d98fe1f68ad2dea2fe78d19c) (03 Nov 2017) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 57dd3dd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57dd3dd28724a150e6c6d4c1c8363e1efd49c197), 09 Nov 2017)</sup>

> ### `setup`: avoid double slashes when looking for `HEAD`
>
> Andrew Baumann reported that when called outside of any Git worktree, `git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree` eventually tries to access `//HEAD`, i.e. any `HEAD` file in the root directory, but with a double slash.
>
> This double slash is not only unintentional, but is allowed by the POSIX standard to have a special meaning. And most notably on Windows, it does, where it refers to a UNC path of the form `//server/share/`.
>
> As a consequence, afore-mentioned `rev-parse` call not only looks for the wrong thing, but it also causes serious delays, as Windows will try to access a server called `HEAD`.
> Let's simply avoid the unintended double slash.

Answer (score 2):

Cygwin doesn't seem to have any way of turning off the UNC path support, but you can shortcut the search by setting `GIT_CEILING_DIRECTORIES` in your environment. My `.zshenv` has:

```
export GIT_CEILING_DIRECTORIES=/:$HOME
```

Which terminates any search at / (avoiding //HEAD) but also at $HOME, since I know it's not inside a repo.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it will be fixed in upstream git. Refs: [discussion thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/alpine.DEB.2.21.1.1711031324110.6482@virtualbox/T/#t), [patch](https://public-inbox.org/git/9322728aaa3010c0b71574eb5876548487d66885.1509713589.git.johannes.schindelin@gmx.de/T/#u)