# Git not working with Ubuntu → Windows Samba shared directory

Tags: git, python-3.x, ubuntu, samba

I am running a Virtual Box Ubuntu VM where I set up my git repository. I then used Samba to create a shared folder and have the following configuration in smb.conf

```
path = /home/allan/git_repo
valid users = allan
read only = no
hide dot files = no
```

When I navigate to the appropriate network location (`\\192.168.65.101\git_repo`) I see all of my files and folders there, including my .git folder which seems to contain everything that I need.

If I navigate to the network location in my bash terminal (MINGW64) I find that it is not recognized as a git repository. A simple command like `git rev-parse HEAD` returns `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`
On the other hand, navigating a sub-directory level down causes some sort of recognition (e.g. I can run `git rev-parse HEAD` and get the valid response). There are plenty of functions though for which I need to be at the upper directory so I'm confused what is happening and how I can solve this issue.

Comment: This is related to another question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512409/gitpython-unable-to-find-head-commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to not execute your git command in the `.git` folder itself.

If should be execute in the parent folder of the `.git/`.

Also, make sure to use the [latest version of Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), as it has a better support of  `\\...` path.
See also "[git tries to stat `//HEAD` when searching for a repo, leading to huge delays on Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47231904/6309)".

---

Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) will recognize that, On Windows, the root level of UNC share is now allowed to be used just like any other directory.

See [commit 5cf7b3b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cf7b3b1acf2e603d92132906bc6929141172d4c), [commit e2683d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e2683d51d96f5e95489d29ee6dfafdde790579e4), [commit d17f212](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d17f2124a7860c2f37eaba574a867dbb4f506c27) (24 Aug 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b57a88a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b57a88a5f1555de6d34d162a1a5a8a6deda8018e), 30 Sep 2019)</sup>

> ### `setup_git_directory()`: handle UNC root paths correctly
>
> When working in the root directory of a file share (this is only possible in Git Bash and Powershell, but not in CMD), the current directory is reported without a trailing slash.
>
> This is different from Unix and standard Windows directories: both `/` and
>   `C:\` are reported with a trailing slash as current directories.
>
> If a Git worktree is located there, Git is not quite prepared for that:
>   while it does manage to find the `.git` directory/file, it returns as length of the top-level directory's path *one more* than the length of the current directory, and `setup_git_directory_gently()` would then
>   return an undefined string as prefix.
>
> In practice, this undefined string usually points to `NUL` bytes, and does not cause much harm. Under rare circumstances that are really involved to reproduce (and not reliably so), the reported prefix could be a suffix string of Git's exec path, though.

More specifically, [`git-for-windows/git` issue 1320](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1320) reported `git status` fails in UNC path at root of Windows share.

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

> ### Fix `.git/` discovery at the root of UNC shares
>
> A very common assumption in Git's source code base is that `offset_1st_component()` returns either 0 for relative paths, or 1 for
>   absolute paths that start with a slash.
>   In other words, the return value is either 0 or points just after the dir separator.
>
> This assumption is not fulfilled when calling `offset_1st_component()` e.g. on UNC paths on Windows, e.g. "`//my-server/my-share`".
>   In this case, `offset_1st_component()` returns the length of the entire string (which is correct, because stripping the last "component" would not result in a
>   valid directory), yet the return value still does not point just after a
>   `dir` separator.
>
> This assumption is most prominently seen in the `setup_git_directory_gently_1()` function, where we want to append a "`.git`" component and simply assume that there is already a dir separator.
>   In the UNC example given above, this assumption is incorrect.
>
> As a consequence, Git will fail to handle a worktree at the top of a UNC
>   share correctly.
>
> Let's fix this by adding a dir separator specifically for that case: we
>   found that there is no first component in the path and it does not end
>   in a dir separator? Then add it.

Comment: Latest version of Git did it!

Comment: @aoh Well done! I knew there was some improvement on UNC path support.

Comment: I'm still having trouble actually making certain git requests (e.g. git status) but will post a separate question about that

Comment: @aoh OK. I will have a look.

Comment: This is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48526991/git-ubuntu-to-windows-changes