# Git Ubuntu to Windows Changes

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu

I am running a Virtual Box Ubuntu VM where I set up my git repository. I then used Samba to create a shared folder and based on another answer ([Git not working with Ubuntu → Windows Samba shared directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513149/git-not-working-with-ubuntu-%E2%86%92-windows-samba-shared-directory)) I updated my git windows version to 2.16.1 (matches my Ubuntu git version)

1. I call git status on my Ubuntu VM and find that I'm on branch "master" and I am up to date
2. I switch to my local machine and on my MINGW64 terminal call git status and after a long delay, a long list of uncommitted changes show up largely "typechange" but some files that are marked as "modified" or "deleted
3. I switch back to my VM and call git status and after a long delay, I'm told that I'm still on master and am up to date. Calling git status another time the delay goes away

What's going on here and how do I fix it? I already tried `git config core.autocrlf true` and `git config core.filemode false`, closed out and re-opened by git terminal and the same issue didn't go away.

Comment: What changes are there, what is supposedly been modified?

Comment: It ranges from "No Newline at end of file" to totally new sections of code being added (or at least being perceived as if they are new)